# Python: capture re-ordering event in a QListWidget?

Tags: python, linux, qt, pyqt

I need to respond to a drag-and-drop re-ordering of items in QListWidget. I can't find an QEvent to use. Any help would be appreciated!

I'm using an eventFilter routine to capture events in my GUI:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

def eventFilter(self, sourceObj, event):
    if event.type()== QtCore.QEvent.Drop:
        print("got to drop event")
        (processing code here)
```

Perhaps this event doesn't trigger on a drag-and-drop re-order of items because the drag-and-drop is internal to the widget (e.g., nothing from outside the widget is dropped on it)?

I've tried `QtCore.QEvent.Drop` and `QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease` without success. Which event should I use?

(I'm using Python3, PyQt4, on Ubuntu 16.10. My eventFilter routine works for other actions in the GUI like clicks, lostFocus ,etc.)

Comment: Try installing the event filter on the QListWidget's viewport

Comment: @Schollii Thanks very much. Installing the event filter on the viewport() did cause the event to trigger. The problem then became that QT does not process the re-ordering of QItems in the QListWidget until after the event. I did find a solution, though: use the ChildRemoved event. Apparently, QT emits that event on a drag-and-drop re-ordering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution I found to work. The solution was to use the eventFilter to listen for the ChildRemoved QEvent. Apparently, QT triggers this event when items in a QListWidget are re-ordered via drag-and-drop.

Step 1. In the **init**(self) for your class that includes the QListWidget, install the event filter for the widget whose event you want to capture.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.lstYourWidgetNameHere.installEventFilter(self)
```

Step 2. In the eventFilter routine in the same class, check for the ChildRemoved QEvent.

```
def eventFilter(self, sourceObj, event):
    objName = str(sourceObj.objectName())
    if event.type()== QtCore.QEvent.ChildRemoved:
        if objName == "lstYourWidgetNameHere":      
            (your code here)
```